Unable to connect a phone wireless using Flutter in Android Studio
I scanned the QR code but stopped there. I am unable to connect wireless with Flutter, although with cable I was able to connect.
What could be causing the issue?

Welcome to SO! Please don't forget to give feedback on what answer actually helped you or not and why. If you found a solution on your own, posting it yourself as answer is welcome.

In terminal write= adb pair 192.168.1.111:90904 (That is example)
And ping you pc ip in mobile
then in terminal write= adb connect 192.168.1.111:90904

I tried but still not working

The QR code method is super unstable, I would recommend another better approach: using the plugin ADB Wi-Fi. In your AndroidStudio, go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Plugins" -> search "adb" -> you will see the "ADB Wi-Fi" -> "install".
The plugin will appear on the right sidebar, just open it -> connect your device with cable -> click on "Connect" for your device -> after connected, unplug your cable -> that's it, your device now is connected wirelessly.


I've encountered a similar problem where connecting via QR Code or pairing code isn't working anymore after a few weeks of smooth operation.
However, I've found a workaround by connecting through the terminal using the command adb connect [phone_ip]:[port]:

You can find the necessary IP address and port details in your phone's settings under Developer Options > Wireless debugging. Once enabled, you'll see the "IP address & Port" listed there.

Is the screen capture of the command needed? Lioke is the color code meaningful?
